# I am trying to submit a form in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

The form tag in html has an attribute class whose value is "cd-form" and when I am putting an action attribute giving the servlet name, it's not working

```
<form class="cd-form" action="Verify">

    <input type="text" name="useid" >
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

so I wanted to ask what should I do to submit the form

Comment: show code please

Comment: Define "not working" ([more info](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/))

Comment: I mean that when I am clicking on Login button, no action is being performed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this way:

```
 <form action="LoginCheck.jsp" method="post">
```

or in your case: Varify.jsp

you need to give as action your jsp and as method post.

Greetings

Comment: Don't get confused with the class attribute in html. It's for CSS. It does not refer to a Java Class (JSP File)